Intercept api request with angular
I need to intercept some API requests in my Angular 18 project.
After some research, I found two potential solutions:

Use fetch and AbortController (this solution works, but I need to use HttpClient, so I can't use it).

Unsubscribe from the observable. Typically, you just need to unsubscribe to stop the request.


I found an example that works:
exemple
However, when I tried this code in my application, it doesn't work. It seems the issue might be related to the Angular version.
Here's the code I tried:
  getData(cancel) {

    return this.http.get(`https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=${8 * 1000}`).pipe(takeUntil(cancel));
  }

  callApi() {

    const cancel: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
    const request = this.getData(cancel).subscribe(result => {
      console.warn('end');
      }
    );

    setTimeout(() => {
      cancel.next(true);
      cancel.complete();
      request.unsubscribe();
    }, 2000);
  }



In the Chrome console, I still see that the request completes.
If anyone can help me with this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks a lot!

In latest versions of angular, http requests auto complete after the requests are made. So there is no need for takeUntil logic.
You need to add all the API calls to a subscription, then on destroy of component ngOnDestroy is called, then all the API calls are cancelled, when you call unsubscribe.
sub: Subscription = new Subscription();
...
getData(cancel) {
    return this.http.get(`https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=${8 * 1000}`);
}
...
callApi() {
    this.sub.add(
        this.getData(cancel).subscribe(result => {
            console.warn('end');
        })
    );
}
...
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
}


Hello,
yes I know, the takeUtil was an attempt after the unsubscribe didn't work.
thx.

@KvnLf did I fix your issue?

no, unfortunately, as I was saying, takeUtil and/or unsubscribe behave in the same way :/

@KvnLf Could you explain clearly what you are trying to do, unsubscribe will stop the API call, what do you mean by intercept and? intercept has a special meaning in  angular, its used to intercept all http request (e.g. adding headers to all http requests)

in reality, I have a page that executes a lot of api calls (a stats dashboard) but these calls can take a long time and when you leave the page, they continue, which slows down my application. So in my component destroy, I'd like to stop the pending requests.
I've had success with the AbortController class (native to javascript) and the fetch method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) but I can't manage it with Angular's HTTPClient.

@KvnLf updated my answer, this is the equivalent of abort controller but for angular

i've just seen an obscure service (several years old) in my application that implements HttpInterceptor. it's probably the one that impacts the behavior of the observable. i'll look into it. Thanks in any case

@KvnLf To be honest this is the solution to the problem you shared, thanks for your time!
